# Secure Cookie Attribute in WebSphere

Tags: cookies, websphere, jsessionid

We are trying to secure our JSESSIONID in our WebSphere Full Profile
I have followed the URL provided:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21422185

Our server configuration:

[image]

Server11_was:

[image]

I have Recycled my node - servers and runtimes. However, The JSESSIONID still coming as not secure.

[image]

Am I missing something?

WebSphere version: 8.5.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also be sure you have the session management option to "**Restrict cookies to HTTPS sessions**" set. You can access this property via this admin console panel:

Servers > Server types > WebSphere application servers > *server_name* > Session management > Enable cookies

For more info, see this Knowledge Center article:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/uprs_rcookie_settings.html?lang=en

Comment: edited my question, the cookies are enabled in session management .